Unable to run Terraform using Self Hosted Linux agent in Azure DevOps
I am having issues in running terraform steps using Azure Devops through self hosted linux agent.
Below is my pipeline code:
trigger:
none
pr:

    ‘*’
    pool:
    name: Self-Hosted-Agent(pool name)
    demands:
        agent.name -equals vmmgmtpuks0019(agent name)
        stages:

    stage: terraform_installation
    jobs:
        job: installation
        steps:
            task: TerraformInstaller@1
            displayName: ‘Terraform installation’
            inputs:
            terraformVersion: ‘latest’

    stage: terraform_init
    jobs:
        job: init
        steps:

            checkout: self

            task: TerraformTaskV4@4
            displayName: ‘Terraform init’
            inputs:
            provider: ‘azurerm’
            command: ‘init’
            workingDirectory: ‘’
            environmentServiceNameAzureRM: '’
            backendServiceArm: ‘’
            backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '’
            backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: ‘’
            backendAzureRmContainerName: '’
            backendAzureRmKey: ‘**’

Terraform installation step is working and below is the logs:
Starting: Terraform installation
Task : Terraform tool installer
Description : Find in cache or download a specific version of Terraform and prepend it to the PATH
Version : 1.216.24
Author : Microsoft Corporation
Help : Learn more about this task

Getting latest Terraform version.
Downloading: https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.7.5/terraform_1.7.5_linux_amd64.zip
Extracting archive
/usr/bin/unzip /package/_work/_temp/terraform-1.7.5-90331641-692a-439d-9d2d-eadd8ae50420.zip
Archive: /package/_work/_temp/terraform-1.7.5-90331641-692a-439d-9d2d-eadd8ae50420.zip
inflating: terraform
Caching tool: terraform 1.7.5 x64
Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /package/_work/_tool/terraform/1.7.5/x64
Verifying Terraform installation…
/package/_work/_tool/terraform/1.7.5/x64/terraform version
Terraform v1.7.5
on linux_amd64
Finishing: Terraform installation

However, the terraform init step is failing with below logs:
Starting: Terraform init
Task : Terraform
Description : Execute terraform commands to manage resources on AzureRM, Amazon Web Services(AWS) and Google Cloud Platform(GCP)
Version : 4.227.24
Author : Microsoft Corporation
Help : Learn more about this task

##[error]Error: Failed to find terraform tool in paths
Finishing: Terraform init

I have even updated the environment variable within the linux machine manually to point to /package/_work/_tool/terraform/1.7.5/x64 and tried allowing access to all hashicorp and terraform related URLs but still terraform init is not completing and giving error. However it is working fine for microsoft hosted agents.

You need to add the TerraformInstaller@1 task before the TerraformTaskV4@4 task within the same job, so that the installed Terraform tool and its PATH environment can be available for the subsequent TerraformTaskV4@4 task in the same job. For more details, see my answer below. @SAUPARNA DATTA

You should install and run Terraform commands in the same job.
Keep in mind that in Azure DevOps Pipelines, each job runs might run on different machines or containers. This means that each job has its own separate environment and does not share state with other jobs.
Something like:
jobs:
  - job: terraform
    displayName: 'Run Terraform'
    steps:
      - checkout: self

      - task: TerraformInstaller@1
        displayName: 'Terraform installation'
        inputs:
          terraformVersion: 'latest'

      - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
        displayName: 'Terraform init'
        inputs:
          provider: 'azurerm'
          command: 'init'
          workingDirectory: ''
          environmentServiceNameAzureRM: ''
          backendServiceArm: ''
          backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: ''
          backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: ''
          backendAzureRmContainerName: ''
          backendAzureRmKey: '**'
      
      # Run other terraform commands here


You need to add the TerraformInstaller@1 task into the same job with the TerraformTaskV4@4 task, and ensure TerraformInstaller@1 task is before the TerraformTaskV4@4 task.
When you run TerraformInstaller@1 task in a job, the task will install the specified version of Terraform from the Internet or the tools cache and prepends it to the PATH of the Azure Pipelines Agent. However, when the job is completed, in the Post-job step, it generally will clean the Terraform path added by the task from PATH.
So, in each jobs you want to run the TerraformTaskV4@4 task or terraform commands, you need to add the TerraformInstaller@1 task.
Since you are using self-hosted agent, another way you can try is directly manually downloading, installing the version of Terraform tool and add it to PATH on the agent machine. Then in the jobs, you can directly run the TerraformTaskV4@4 task or terraform commands without the TerraformInstaller@1 task.
